# Not to create file using download.file in R

Tags: r

When I am trying to download a web-page using download.file() in R and there is no such website, function automatically creates an empty file.

How can I avoid creating empty files?

Comment: What is wrong with either: 1) Don't try to download a page that doesn't exist. 2) Delete the empty file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the `url.exists` function from **RCurl** as a conditional statement:

```
library(RCurl)
myurl <- 'http://www.google.com'
if(url.exists(myurl))
    download.file(myurl, 'myfile.html')
```